# The commandText property is not properly initialized

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to implement data into 2 (later on 3) tables simultaneously using a C# console application. I want to implement into table 'user' a firstname, lastname and userID, user ID will be auto incremented.

That same userID should also be implemented into table 'profile' along with a porilfeID (once again, done autoamtically by auto increment) and a profileName.

But somewhere it throws the error of commandtext not properly initialized and I cant figure out anymore what I am doing wrong.

```
class SQLCreate
{
    public void create(int entries)
    {
        string ConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=databaseassignment;";

        MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;

        conn = new MySqlConnection();

        int entryValue = entries;
        conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;

        try
        {
            Stopwatch stopw = new Stopwatch();
            stopw.Start();
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            cmd.Connection = conn;

            for (int i = 0; i < entryValue; i++)
            {
          
                MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName)", conn);
                //MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName) VALUES (@firstName, @lastName)", conn);
    
    
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", "John");
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", "Doe");
    
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
                int userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO profile (userId, profileName) VALUES (@userId, @profileName)", conn);
    
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profileName", "John Doe");
                    
                cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
                string firstName = Faker.Name.First();
                string lastName = Faker.Name.Last();
                string profileName = Faker.Name.First();
    
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", MySqlDbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = firstName;
    
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", MySqlDbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = lastName;
    
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@profileName", MySqlDbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters["@profileName"].Value = profileName;
    
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
            stopw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(" Time elapsed: {0} ", stopw.Elapsed);
        } catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Error messages normally come with line numbers!! Please show us ALL the error message

Comment: When crerate new instance of MySqlCommand obj
new MySqlCommand( ... )   this constauctor 's parameter is connection string or commandtext ? 
or you should write it like   
cmd1 = new MySqlCommand();
cmd1.CommandText = "Insert Into ..."...
+And you forgot to assign connection to  cmd2 , cmd3

Answer (score 0):

You create `cmd = new MySqlCommand();` but never set its `.CommandText` property. Calling `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` will fail because there's no `CommandText` to execute.

Either set `cmd.CommandText` or change the constructor to `cmd = new MySqlCommand("text here", conn);`.